# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $_name not working

Tags: zend-db-table, zend-framework, tablename

I encountered a problem regarding changing default table name

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Game extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'games';
```

Error:

Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gamenomad_dev.game' doesn't exist

Help me... it's supposed to be simple!

*EDIT
The problem here is that Zend Framework is supposed to detect the changed table name from the default 'game' into 'games'.

Comment: show us the line where the problem actually is. and the full error msg.

Comment: Well you have to create the table yourself (with `CREATE TABLE games (...`), the `Zend_Db`-components do not create the tables automatically. Edit: Btw in the error message the table is called `game` and in DbTable it's `games` which one is correct?

Comment: The problem is that Zend Framework supposed to detect the change $_name so that it doesn't look for the default table name 'game' but instead the changed table name 'games'. And the table 'games' does exist.

Answer (score 0):

In ZF you have to **hardcode** your database table to model. It doesn't scan for database changes. You have two ways:

**Create class with table name**

```
class Game extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    // default table name: game
}
```

If you want to use ZF's default paths, you should put DBTable model into `application/models/dbtable` directory and name your class like `Application_Model_DbTable_Game` - then ZF knows it has to look for `game` table

**Create class with any name**

e.g. `ExtraGameTable` and set its parameters to show table name:

```
class ExtraGameTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'game';
}
```

As stated in documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html

> If you don't specify the table name, it defaults to the name of the
>   class. If you rely on this default, the class name must match the
>   spelling of the table name as it appears in the database.

You may try to combine it with some configuration file and load table names from there, but still - ZF won't know anything about underlying database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Show the actual line and stacktrace to your problem, maybe you are generating your query in a way it doesn't read the actual table name.